# Zoom to the centre of canvas using Fabric

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs, zooming

I'm implementing the Zoom functionality on canvas with fabric.js. I achieved zooming but somehow its not zooming to centre of canvas. Its zooming to top-left corner of canvas.

Below is my JS for the same.

```
<script>
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("Canvas-Id", {
    selection: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 400
  });

  canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://i24.photobucket.com/albums/c22/smeagolsfree/TSCHQ.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height
  });

  initializeCanvas(canvas)

</script>
```

In my JS file:

```
var initializeCanvas;

initializeCanvas = function(canvas) {
  var MAX_ZOOM_IN, MAX_ZOOM_OUT, SCROLL_SIZE, ZOOM_PERCENT, zoomIn, zoomOut;
  SCROLL_SIZE = 120;
  ZOOM_PERCENT = 1.2;
  MAX_ZOOM_IN = 5;
  MAX_ZOOM_OUT = 1;

  zoomIn = function() {
    if(canvas.getZoom() < MAX_ZOOM_IN) {
      canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * ZOOM_PERCENT);
      $('.flaticon-zoom-in').removeClass('disable');
    } else {
      $('.flaticon-zoom-in').addClass('disable');
    }
    $('.flaticon-zoom-out').removeClass('disable');
  };

  zoomOut = function() {
    if(canvas.getZoom() > MAX_ZOOM_OUT) {
      canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / ZOOM_PERCENT);
      $('.flaticon-zoom-out').removeClass('disable');
    } else {
      $('.flaticon-zoom-out').addClass('disable');
    }
    $('.flaticon-zoom-in').removeClass('disable');
  };

  $('#zoomIn').click(function() {
    zoomIn();
  });

  $('#zoomOut').click(function() {
    zoomOut();
  });

  $('.taggable-image-canvas-container').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / SCROLL_SIZE > 0) ? zoomIn() : zoomOut()
  });
};
```

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve zooming to centre of canvas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the expected behavior of setZoom function which is calling zoomToPoint with the top left point as an argument:

```
setZoom: function (value) {
  this.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(0, 0), value);
  return this;
}
```

So, zooming on center of the canvas can be achieved by calling `zoomToPoint`:

```
canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), canvas.getZoom() / ZOOM_PERCENT);
```